# Add Multiple Attribtues to a Single Multi-Valued Property

Tags: 2013

Is it possible to take separate AD attributes (IE; address, city, state), and then populate all three into a **single** multi-valued user property in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Sure just use a serialization - JSON for example or seperate them with a special char (like ';').
Remember that the max length for a userprofile property is 3600 chars.

I would do it with a few lines of code. Guess its not possible with the OOTB synch.

Remember that you need to use code again to read the information.

Comment: I'm using the AD sync, and have no problem mapping single Active Directory attributes to a single custom property. But we have four attributes in our accounts that hold a street, city, state, and zip. I could map each one to a single user property, but I was hoping there was a way to import those four into just one multi-valued property , so that in the user's profile it would appear on a single line .